# Почему одни .jar файлы надо подключать командой --module-path ... --add-modules, а другие командой -cp?

Tags: java, сборка, javac

Отдельная либа javafx, подключение в проект по типу:

```
java -cp ...
```

Не работает. Нужно писать:

```
java --module ... --add-modules.
```

Но почему так?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятный. О каком проекте вообще идёт речь?